# How can we compare each element array and show the element based on the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table to displayed with header and row values, row values will be fetched from API and head values will be hard coded.

But we will not be displaying one column based on the prop value for each row.
i.e, this.props.members[array of rows].show_col_volume = true.

So i have mappped the show_col_volume for all the rows using the below code and stored in a variable

And now we have volume variable array of boolean items for each rows.Then by iterating forEach i am checking for each index and writing the condition for displaying

```
const volume=  this.props.members.map((val, i) => {
      if(val.show_volume_column === true){
             return true
           }
        else{
          return false;
        }
  });

<span style={{ width: '40%' }}><FormattedMessage {...messages.tableDetailsHeadPremiumLabel} /></span>
 //If the particular index of row has true then we need to display the corresponding column else we will not be displaying

  {volume.forEach(function(show){
     console.log(show,"show")
     if(show === true){
           return  <span style={{ width: '20%' }}><FormattedMessage {...messages.tableDetailsHeadVolumeLabel} /></span>;
     }
     else{
       return null
     }
   })}
```

```
//Place where table rows are displayed
</thead><tbody>{rows}</tbody></Table>
  }
```

My problem is for all the cases even though the particular index row value is true but i am unable to see the column displayed for

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  return this.props.members.map(member => {    
    return (member.show_volume_column && (
        <span style={{ width: "20%" }}>
          <FormattedMessage {...messages.tableDetailsHeadVolumeLabel} />
        </span>
    ))
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this but if 5 array of indexes returns true then we are able to see the same header column is repeated to 5 times in all the rows. Please advise